# How to get all index of collection cells in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an array in collectionView cell. with start index [0,3] and last index is 5,3. how to i will get vertically index between [0,3], [5,3]. like [1,3], [2,3], [3,3], [4,3] in collectionView cell in swift 3.?

Comment: please update your question with some code about, how you defined the array and how you are appending the data to it.

Comment: My array array is ["0,3","5,3"], ["2,3", "2,7"], ["2,1", "7,1"]. where in array  ["0,3","5,3"] at index 0. I have section 0 and row 3 and at index 1. I have section 5 and row 3. My problem is how to i will get ["1,3", ''2,3", "3,3", "4,3"] index in array.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: _"an array in collectionView cell"_. What is that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that builds a list of all valid index paths for the collection view, and then filters only the ones between a start index and an end index:

```
func findIndexes(from collectionView: UICollectionView, between startIndex: IndexPath, and endIndex: IndexPath) -> [IndexPath] {

    // build the list of all possible index paths
    let allIndexPaths = (0..<collectionView.numberOfSections).flatMap { section in
        return (0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)).map { item in
            return IndexPath(item: item, inSection: section)
        }
    }

    // filter the ones in range
    return filteredIndexPaths = allIndexPaths.filter { indexPath in
        return startIndex < indexPath && indexPath < endIndex
    }
}
```